# Change table value based on value of previous element

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

How would use greasemonkey to change the value of the 3rd row on the condition that the first row has the value "China"? All the other answers I found involves looking at the element id, but my code doesnt have any.

```
<td class="listRow listHighlight" align="center">101</td>

    <tr id="country3" class="listRow">

        <td class="listRow listHighlight" align="center">China</td>

        <td class="listRow listHighlight" align="center">Asia</td>

        <td class="listRow listHighlight" align="center">31</td>

    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and [next()](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/):

```
var third = $('.listRow td:contains("China")').next().next();
if (third.text() === '31') {
    third.text('32');
}
```

In case the first cell may have words except `China` like `China something` the selector approach won't work, you'll need an exact comparison. Use [filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var third = $('.listRow td:first').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'China';
}).next().next().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === '31';
}).text('32');
```

Or a combined version:

```
var third = $('.listRow td:first').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === 'China') {
        var third = $(this).next().next();
        if (third.text() === '31') {
            third.text('32');
        }
    }
});
```